# How can I use Wireshark to capture ROS packets?

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I want to analyze ROS network traffic directly from wireshark. What are the steps to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229610/how-can-i-use-wireshark-to-capture-ros-packets?/) by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2016-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-20**:
Duplicate of [What are the tools and their usage to analyze ROS traffic and network time delay of ros tcp and udp messages?](http://answers.ros.org/question/229543/what-are-the-tools-and-their-usage-to-analyze-ros-traffic-and-network-time-delay-of-ros-tcp-and-udp-messages/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I want to analyze ROS network traffic directly from wireshark

Capturing ROS traffic is no different from how you'd normally use Wireshark. If you don't yet know how Wireshark works, I suggest you find a suitable tutorial and read up on that first.

Using it 'with' ROS should then be easy.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1